# What column to index on and making table search fast

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have a table that holds stats for a game, this table will have hundreds of thousands of lines in but i need to it be searchable for the stats pages of the game.

I am not sure what I need to do regarding indexing and how to keep the table searchable in a realistic time. I normally index the Id field which is a primary key. I don't really understand indexing so am not sure if I am doing the correct thing.

Can anyone lend some advice please? I am using a MySQL database.

Thanks.

Comment: It might be worthwhile to cache some common search results (and do a disclaimer that they may not be completely real-time).

Comment: Well, I am going to run a cron to gather all the results for each player and store totals so the DB won't get out of control. I hope this will have a similar effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rule of thumb - index columns that you are using in the `WHERE` clause and those being used in the `ORDER BY`.

You should always, however, test the effects of the change - sometimes adding indexes can *cause* performance problems.

I suggest reading one of the many [tutorials](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1382791/Optimizing-MySQL-Queries-and-Indexes.htm) on optimizing mysql and following the advice with your table.

Comment: @freddy K. - I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: It reads like columns which are being used in `WHERE` **and** `ORDER BY` clause (like: `.. where column_a=1 order by column_a`). But the index should also be on column_a if it's like `.. where column_b=1 order by column_a` (and another index on `column_b`)

Comment: @freddy K. - I see now. Thanks - answer clarified.